# Bean Validation for Super class

Tags: java, apache-camel

Hi I have a question regarding Bean Validation (JSR-303). We can validate one bean against set of annotations provided in a bean. What if i have a Bean Car which extends Bean Vehicle, and if i pass Bean Car to the validator, how to make Bean Vehicle(i.e. Super Class) also get Validated ?

I am using this Bean Validation in Camel. Below is my Code

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:data/source?noop=true").process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Process 1");
            Car car = new Car();
            //this property is of Super Class
            //car.setVehicleId(1);
            car.setName("Swift");
            car.setCompany("Maruti");

            exchange.getIn().setBody(car);
        }
    }).to("bean-validator://v").process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Exchange is : "+arg0.getIn().getBody(Car.class));
        }
    });
}
```

My Car Bean is

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String company;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }   
}
```

My Vehicle Bean is

```
public class Vehicle {
    @NotNull
    private int vehicleId;

    public int getVehicleId() {
        return vehicleId;
    }

    public void setVehicleId(int vehicleId) {
        this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
    }   
}
```

Thank you. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this not work? http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working. The problem is i have used primitive types in Vehicle [ private **int** vehicleId; ]
So i corrected it with [ private **Integer** vehicleId; ]. So after this my Vehicle bean is

```
public class Vehicle {
    @NotNull
    private Integer vehicleId;

    public Integer getVehicleId() {
        return vehicleId;
    }

    public void setVehicleId(Integer vehicleId) {
        this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
    }   
}
```